Why can’t Windows 10 cannot reach file system in SD card when using a USB card reader?
I have a Windows 10 computer and am using a Sabrent SD card reader to attempt to read my SD card since my laptop does not have a native card reader. When inserting the SD card + reader into my computer, it shows the USB Drive as being mapped to Drive D, however no files are accessible. I'm entirely unable to reach the files on the SD card or assign a new drive letter.
The card and reader show up in my Disk Manager as Disk 1 and Disk 2, with Disk 1 being the SD card without a drive letter, and Disk 2 seemingly being the USB reader which has a drive letter but no partitions. When trying to assign Disk 1 to a drive letter, the system says it cannot find the file specified.

I know common issues are a broken SD card reader, or a bad SD card, however I'm using the SD card in a Zoom H4N Pro and the recorder is able to read and write data to the card with no issues.
This is also the 3rd SD card reader I've tried so at this point I'm confident that is not the issue either.

I'm using the SD card in an audio recorder Which device exactly? It likely uses a filesystem and/or partitioning layout Windows doesn't support. That won't be solved with different hardware or media, it's that simple. Please [edit] the question with the requested information.

Done, but to reiterate the info I added, I'm using a Zoom H4n recorder and it formatted the card into a FAT32 format based on what I remember and information in the manual

This device supposedly has a USB interface itself, tried that yet? If possible, please also list the other SD readers you tried.

As above. The device has two USB modes: Audio and Storage. The latter shouldn't be any different than any external SD card reader except insofar it supports whatever format it uses. By format, as previously mentioned I mean either the filesystem, the partitioning or both and it must be something unusual because the machine always asks to format any new/blank card, according to the manual. Connect it as "Storage" and check the properties.

Also all the information online suggests the usage of the recorder itself as a SD card reader ("Storage" mode) to transfer files. Nowhere is mentioned you can simply read it from the SD card in any standard SD card reader.

One reason Disk Management would list a disk like this and not recognize the partition isn’t an unsupported file system was being used. It does not appear you are 100% confident that FAT32 or exFAT actually is the file system. Your screenshot suggests it’s likely not the case.
